# Disable buttons while keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I made an app which includes an UITextField and an UITableView.
I'd like to disable all functions/buttons of the UITableView if the user is typing some text into the UITextField. So if the user uses the UITextField it's not possible to swipe left over a UITableViewCell (normaly a delete botton comes up). So the user only can use the UITextFiled while the keyboard is displayed.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use textfield delegate methods

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
         //check if(textfield==yourtextfield) if you have more than one textfields
           tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable buttons when the `keyboardWillShow` (and WillHide) notifications are called in the NSNotificationCenter.

Simply call `YES` in the selector that is called from `KeyboardWillHide` and `NO` in the other

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //disable button here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your UITextField's delegate method:

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string 
{    
if (theTextField == yourTextField){    
   yourButtonOutlet.userInteractionEnabled = NO;    
 }
}
```

Comment: This answer is only valid when user is typing.. Buttons should be disabled as the textField becomes first responder like the answer above suggests.